# No http handler was found for request type 'GET' in dotnetnuke

Tags: asp.net, iis, dotnetnuke

Dnn data base and files of dotnetnuke moved to new host but when starting it show error:

```
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

i have checked log file of dnn in `\Portals\_default\Logs` it shows error :

```
2016-10-16 19:09:25,763 [WIN-MA182KN2LA7][Thread:7][ERROR] DotNetNuke.Entities.Urls.UrlRewriterUtils - System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Error executing child request for ~/Default.aspx. ---> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): No http handler was found for request type 'GET'
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapIntegratedHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig, Boolean convertNativeStaticFileModule)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(String path, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(String path, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path, Boolean preserveForm)
   at DotNetNuke.Entities.Urls.AdvancedUrlRewriter.Handle404OrException(FriendlyUrlSettings settings, HttpContext context, Exception ex, UrlAction result, Boolean transfer, Boolean showDebug)
   at DotNetNuke.Entities.Urls.AdvancedUrlRewriter.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context, Uri requestUri, Boolean useFriendlyUrls, UrlAction result, FriendlyUrlSettings settings, Boolean allowSettingsChange, Guid parentTraceId)
```

i have checked url rewitemodule in iis . it has been installed . Domain name is correct to

Comment: Google `No http handler was found for request type 'GET'`. You'll find a lot of results. This is probably not DNN related, but more likely to be an IIS/hosting problem. This is assuming you copied the web.config from old to new hosting...

Comment: all things works , when i enter wrong url , server understand it and redirect 404, but handling *.aspx was not defined in handler mapping and cuased error

Answer (score 0):

Handling `*.aspx` is not defined in iis. go into

```
 IIS manager --> Default Website --> handler Mapping
```

Check if you have a mapping for aspx... ideally you should see 2 mappings for .aspx...

you can also use the command line to get the info by the following:

C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd list config "Default Web Site" -section:handlers >"give output txt file name"

[image: Check that handler is defined or not]