# Hosting Company under cyber attack!! Can I fix this myself or do I wait for the hosting company?

Tags: dotnetnuke

Our hosting company MijnHostingPartner.nl got hit badly by a cyber attack and most of their client's website have been down for weeks. I am a complete noob in coding, just working my way around it by using DNN to build a website. I've set up all the MSSQL DB's correctly and it's running smoothly for over a year now.

Since it's used daily by a small community of ten pin league bowlers - all results and news are displayed here - I'm getting quite the amount of complaints since it's down!

This is the error I get on both top-level as sub-level domains:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
No http handler was found for request type 'GET'
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: No http handler was found for request type 'GET'

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[HttpException (0x80004005): No http handler was found for request type 'GET']
   System.Web.HttpApplication.MapIntegratedHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig, Boolean convertNativeStaticFileModule) +748
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(String path, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) +589

[HttpException (0x80004005): Error executing child request for ~/ErrorPage.aspx.]
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(String path, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) +1295
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path, Boolean preserveForm) +72
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path) +45
   DotNetNuke.Common.Initialize.CheckVersion(HttpApplication app) +845
   DotNetNuke.Common.Initialize.InitializeApp(HttpApplication app, Boolean& initialized) +154
   DotNetNuke.Common.Initialize.Init(HttpApplication app) +157
   DotNetNuke.HttpModules.RequestFilter.RequestFilterModule.FilterRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +258
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +139
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +195
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +88

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3282.0
```

Does anyone have a clue what I'm talking about? 'Cause I sure don't. Please, if you explain it to me, explain in a way your dog would understand, if that's even possible.

Many thanks,

Robbe

Comment: This looks to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40072139/no-http-handler-was-found-for-request-type-get-in-dotnetnuke - try the suggestions on that question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a third-party hosting solution I would guess that you don't have the ability to change the values referenced in the comments section.

This error appears to be a very low-level issue with the server not being configured for ASP.NET hosting.  (The underlying technology used by DNN.)

I'm not confident that you will have the ability to fix this without them.  However, you have a few options.

1. Get the information on this error to the hosting provider.  The key will be to determine if ANY services work  A great check is to see if you can get the DNN Keep Alive to work.  You can get to that via http://yoursite.com/keepalive.aspx
2. Extract a copy of the site files & database and move to another host.  This is typically an easy option, but I would caution you that it would be prudent to have the site scanned for any potential malicious impacts PRIOR to moving to a new hosting provider unless you know for sure what the impact was to your hosting provider.

This is never a good situation, but one that you should be able to get past.  If needed, this could be a time to reach out to someone that knows this stuff well, as there are a lot of little risks associated with a potentially compromised solution.